# Email to multiple recipients breaks on error handler

Tags: vba, excel, email

I am trying to use the standard code to email a workbook to multiple recipients but build in some error handling that is likely to arise in my model.

If the email address is not available the cell where the email address would be found would read "Pending Search...".

If that is the case the loop simply needs to skip that cell and move on the the next email address.

Below is my code. The issue is coming from the IF/Then/Next line. I am getting a Next without For error. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Mail_workbook_Outlook_1()


    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim Position_In_Loop As Long
    Dim Total_Emails As Long
    Dim Email_Address As String
    Dim Dashboard As Worksheet
        Set Dashboard = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard")
    Dim Body As Range
        Set Body = Dashboard.Range("F13")
    Dim Attachment As Range
        Set Attachment = Dashboard.Range("F24")


    With Dashboard
            Total_Emails = Dashboard.Range("G3")
    End With

    For Position_In_Loop = 1 To Total_Emails

        Email_Address = Dashboard.Range("C3").Offset(Position_In_Loop, 0)

        If Email_Address = "Pending Search..." Then Next Position_In_Loop

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            On Error Resume Next
                With OutMail
                    .To = "Email_Address"
                    .CC = ""
                    .BCC = ""
                    .Subject = "Open Job Violations"
                    .Body = "Body"
                    .Attachments.Add (Attachment)
                    .Send
                End With
            On Error GoTo 0

        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing

    Next Position_In_Loop


End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't increment the loop like that.  You are going to skip emails.  Wrap the whole the Outlook mail code in an If statement.
    Option Explicit

```
Sub Mail_workbook_Outlook_1()


    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim Position_In_Loop As Long
    Dim Total_Emails As Long
    Dim Email_Address As String
    Dim Dashboard As Worksheet
    Set Dashboard = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard")
    Dim Body As Range
    Set Body = Dashboard.Range("F13")
    Dim Attachment As Range
    Set Attachment = Dashboard.Range("F24")

    With Dashboard
        Total_Emails = Dashboard.Range("G3")
    End With

    For Position_In_Loop = 1 To Total_Emails

        Email_Address = Dashboard.Range("C3").Offset(Position_In_Loop, 0)

        If Email_Address <> "Pending Search..." Then

            Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = "Email_Address"
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "Open Job Violations"
                .Body = "Body"
                .Attachments.Add Attachment
                .Send
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0

            Set OutMail = Nothing
            Set OutApp = Nothing
        End If
    Next Position_In_Loop


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

change this line 
`If Email_Address = "Pending Search..." Then Next Position_In_Loop`
to

```
If Email_Address = "Pending Search..." Then 
 Position_In_Loop=Position_In_Loop+1
end if
```

Comment: Will this also work for two (or more) consecutive `Pending Search...`?

Comment: You should only use parenthesis when assign a value.  Removing the parenthesis might solve it.